# Has a prototype been built to demonstrate the claims made by WO 2001053721 A1?

Tags: claims, wo2001053721, us20010032522

The publication number of the patent in question is WO2001053721 A1. Simply put, has a thruster been built and do the claims in the patent represent reality?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the post to Ask Patents. This is a site for asking questions about the US patent system and for seeking help in uncovering prior art on existing US applications and granted patents. It is **not particularly likely** that this post will be seen by the inventor.

The document you referenced is an international patent application. From google patent you can see that there is a corresponding US application US20010032522. Looking that up in the USPTO Public PAIR database, this application went abandoned in Oct. 2001 for a lack of a response to an initial rejection and never became an actual patent. For more recent applications, the whole back-and-forth of papers between the applicant and the USPTO are visible on PAIR.

The application looks like it was written by someone who studied the book "Patent it Yourself" by David Pressman.